# Difference between two reference variables in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

It is possible to create object and store it in reference `variable(obj1)` which has data type of same name as that of class name and object can also be stored in reference `variable(obj2)` which has data type `var`. Is there any difference in both the methods and does they both work the same?

```
void main()
{
   Operation obj1=new Operation();
   var obj2=new Operation();
}
class Operation
{
   int add(int num1, int num2)
   {
       return num1+num2;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

- var: A way to declare a variable without specifying its type [dart](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour)
- The flutter documentation also does not recommend duplicating the definition
- the var will be type-checked against the value
- so.

```
  Operation obj1=new Operation(); //not suggested
  var obj2 = Operation(); // best practice
```